# XSLT to check content prior to mapping

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need some help with XSLT to check each of the Source `<Info>` elements with `@Type="bar"`.

If their child `<Ref>` elements are contained in the child `<Ref>` elements of the `<Info>` elements with `@Type="foo"`,
I want a `<Info>` with `@Type="foo"` created in the target with the same `<Refs>`.

I struggle with the lack of dynamically updatebale variables in XSLT !

See source and  expected target below

**Source**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Infos>
        <Info Type="foo">
            <Refs>
                <Ref>1</Ref>
                <Ref>2</Ref>
                <Ref>3</Ref>
            </Refs>
            <Content>FOO CONTENT</Content>
        </Info>
        <Info Type="bar">
            <Refs>
                <Ref>1</Ref>
                <Ref>2</Ref>
            </Refs>
            <Content>BAR 1 CONTENT</Content>
        </Info>
        <Info Type="bar">
            <Refs>
                <Ref>3</Ref>
            </Refs>
            <Content>BAR 2 CONTENT</Content>
        </Info>
        <Info Type="bar">
            <Refs>
                <Ref>4</Ref>
            </Refs>
            <Content>BAR 3 CONTENT</Content>
        </Info>
    </Infos>
```

**Expected Target**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Infos>
    <Info Type="foo">
        <Refs>
            <Ref>1</Ref>
            <Ref>2</Ref>
        </Refs>
        <Content>FOO CONTENT</Content>
    </Info>
        <Info Type="foo">
        <Refs>
            <Ref>3</Ref>
        </Refs>
        <Content>FOO CONTENT</Content>
    </Info>
    <Info Type="bar">
        <Refs>
            <Ref>1</Ref>
            <Ref>2</Ref>
        </Refs>
        <Content>BAR 1 CONTENT</Content>
    </Info>
    <Info Type="bar">
        <Refs>
            <Ref>3</Ref>
        </Refs>
       <Content>BAR 2 CONTENT</Content
    </Info>
    <Info Type="bar">
        <Refs>
            <Ref>4</Ref>
        </Refs>
       <Content>BAR 3 CONTENT</Content
    </Info>
</Infos>
```

So note two  foo elements created as the original had refs 1,2,3 and there is a bar with 1,2 and a bar with 3.

Also the original bar elements get mapped exactly as per source .

Comment: The required logic is not clear at all. `<Ref>3</Ref>` appears both under `foo` and under `bar`; why should it be treated differently?

Comment: I updated the Target to have the bar element in same order as source , Is this the difference you refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly (which is not at all certain), you want to do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="foo" match="Info[@Type='foo']" use="Refs/Ref" />

<xsl:template match="/Infos">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Info[@Type='bar'][key('foo', Refs/Ref)]" mode="foo"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Info[@Type='bar']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Info" mode="foo">
    <Info Type="foo">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Refs"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('foo', Refs/Ref)/*[not(self::Refs)]"/>
    </Info>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Basically, this takes all `bar` nodes that have a match with one of the references listed under `foo`, recreates them as `foo` nodes and copies the content from the matching `foo` node. Then it copies all the `bar` nodes *as is*.

Comment: Not exactly the nodes may have more unique content , So the the nodes that are created must be based on the original foo nodes

Comment: Updated the Source and target to reflect above comment

Comment: @CCoy You can copy the extra content using the same key.

Comment: Thank you for above solution and for highlighting the availability of the<xsl:key> .